# Xcode: ViewController shows no .view or addSubview: methods

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, media-player, subview

I created two ViewControllers (Xcode 4 => Storyboard). After that I created two UIViewSubclasses, called PlayOutControlViewController.h and TVOutViewController.h.

I want to display a video on an external Display, so I tried the following:

(MediaPlayer.framework added, Changed the class of my UIViewSubclasses to PlayOut... and TVOut... - Controller.h)

```
PlayoutViewController.m

[TVOutViewController.view addSubview: MediaPlayer.view];
//Got Error: Property view not found on object of type TVOutViewController

[TVOutViewController addSubview: MediaPlayer.view]; //Got an Error
//Got Error: No known class method for selector addSubview
```

Sorry, I know what the Errors mean, but not how to fix them.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I'm in the PlayoutViewController.m, where:

```
[self.view addSubview: (anyUIView)];
//works

//and

[PlayoutViewController.view addSubview: (anyUIView)];
//won't work.
```

... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks so far.

My TVOutViewController is a subclass of UIViewController, as described here:

```
@interface TVOutViewController : UIViewController {    }
```

I added a UIView to the TVOutViewController in InterfaceBuilder. Do I have to do something else to be able to do like:

```
[self.view addSubview: AnyUIView];
```

Second question:

If I declare a method in TVOutViewController.m, like:

```
+(void)addSubviewMethod:(id)sender { [self.view addSubview: AnyUIView]; }
```

Why am I not able to call it in the PlayoutControlViewController.m via

```
[TVOutViewController addSubviewMethod];
```

I added

```
#import "TVOutViewController.h";
```

to the PlayOutViewController.m file.

Thank you all in advance!

OK SOLVED:

You were on the right track:

I forgot to initialize the object. Now it works like a charm!

```
TVOutViewController *MoviePlayerView = [[TVOutViewController alloc] init];
[MoviePlayerView.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
```

Answer (score 1):

A class and its instances are different things.

`self.view` works, because instances of class PlayoutViewController have `view` property.

`PlayoutViewController.view` doesn't, because the class object itself does not have this property. The same applies to TVOutViewController — you should call an instance, not the class itself.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Could you maybe do an example for me on how to call these instances? Thank you!

Comment: @Darwin The same way as you call `self` instance. How did you create objects of type TVOutViewController?